# Semantic-UI-React could not enable debug

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, semantic-ui-react, next.js

I am using semantic-ui-react and I am trying to create snapshot tests using jest. However, I keep getting this message. Could someone shed some light on this? I am using semantic with nextjs.

```
console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:36
      Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update references to remove this warning.
    console.error node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/lib/debug.js:30
      Semantic-UI-React could not enable debug.
    console.error node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/lib/debug.js:31
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to get this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

This warning is produced when debug can't deal with localStorage, but it shouldn't be called for tests. Make sure that the ENV vars are set correctly, you need to have `NODE_ENV=test`.

Comment: Can you create a minimal repro repository on github? I will check it.

Comment: Still with the problem when running tests

Comment: Please make a minimal repro repository. Also, if you're using Windows, try https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env to set ENV var.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either (using cross-env and latest of everything)

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't solve the problem with setting `NODE_ENV=test`. Anotherr option is to use or extend some test setup script (ie mocha -r setup.js):

```
// if you run Enzyme tests then you probably already have this import which creates global.window object
import 'jsdom-global/register'

global.window.localStorage = {};
```

For me both options work. I am running my tests on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? If so, how do you execute the tests? I was facing the same issue earlier and was able to resolve it.

I had the following in my package.json:

```
"run_test" : "set NODE_ENV=test && npm run test",
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
```

The problem with this, however, is that windows will set your NODE_ENV as "test " and not as "test", notice the trailing whitespace. The solution for me was to fix write the scripts by removing the whitespace:

```
"run_test" : "set NODE_ENV=test&&npm run test",
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
```